# c++ If all condition are met

Tags: c++, if-statement

Is there any way to check if all conditions are met?
e.g:

```
if(num[i] > (*all*)alt[c])
{
}
```

Instead of doing it this way

```
if(num[i] > alt[1] && num[i] > alt[2] && num[i] > alt[3])
{
}
```

Like is there a shorter way?

Comment: i think you want std::find_if

Comment: `std::all_of(alt.begin(), alt.end(), [](T t) { return num[i] > t });` (see [all_of](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of))

Comment: Thank you Borgleader. Now that is a _lot_ prettier ;)

Comment: if there's at least one element, you can also use `max_element`.

Comment: What is the type of `alt`? Is its length known at compile-time? How about its values?

Comment: can you explain it a bit am A noob

Comment: @Borgleader you're too fast to compete !  Put your comment as answer so that we can upvote it

Comment: @Borgleader How can i Add that to the if-Statement?

Comment: @ChrysUgwu Theres a usage example on the documentation page, the link is in my previous comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you can take the maximum of all `alts`, and then compare `num[i]` to it.

Get the maximum element with:

```
auto max = std::max_element(alt.begin(), alt.end());
```

Comment: is there any library i need to add?

Comment: Oh, is alt a simple array? int alt[10] ? If so, use std::begin(alt) and std::end(alt)

Answer (score 9):

You could use a suitable auxiliary function which effectively just calls one of the algorithms, e.g.:

```
 if (is_bigger(num[i], alts)) {
     // ...
 }
```

where the function `is_bigger()` just uses `std::all_of()` with a suitable condition:

```
template <typename T, typename Sequence>
bool is_bigger(T const& test, Sequence const& alts) {
    return std::all_of(alts.begin(), alts.end(),
         [&](T const& other){ return test > other; });
}
```

`all_of()` is simple an algorithm which applies a predicate to all elements in the sequence delimited by the begin and end iterator (`alts.begin()` and `alts.end()`). The other thing in this function is simple a lambda expression creating a corresponding predicate.

Comment: That will work, but if OP wants to test this for each of the `num`s, finding the maximum once and comparing each num to it is more efficient.

Comment: @zmbq: I just answered the question rather than the suspected question. Based on the OP's response I realize that you guessed right. Seems my Clairvoyance Hat is defective today.

Answer (score 0):

For now no, at least without creating additional code (instead of evaluating at compile-time). But if you use 'inline' variables (currently only an early draft - idea of mine), you could write:

```
auto FuncCheckingMulCond(auto &inline varSrc, auto &inline varTarget, inline size_t nTimes)
{
    for(inline size_t i(0); i < nTimes; ++i)
        if(!(varSrc > varTarget[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

And so your example will look like this:

```
if(FuncCheckingMulCond(num[i], alt, 5))
{
}
```

Inline variables should be such which value is known at compile-time and as 'FuncCheckingMulCond' contain 'inline' parameters it should be evaluated at compile-time too. '&inline' is an inline reference which means that it instead of storing some pointer, all it's instances are replaced with the variable it had bound to. So in theory - the above code should do exactly the thing you wanted, but unfortunately this isn't part of ISO C++ yet.

Comment: More of inline [variables](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/ej8T6Iyl8VM).